# Using undisclosed-recipients:; in Swiftmailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send an email with a ton of recipients in the BCC field. I'm trying to set the To: field as `unknown-recipients:;` but every time I try, I get an error that the email doesn't conform to a normal email address:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' with message 'Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.' in[...]
```

Is there any way to send to undisclosed recipients using SwiftMailer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "undisclosed recipient" is usually considered as spam except if sent from one of your contacts and is implemented by using BCC field for all recipients + your own email (or any public email you don't mind to be visible) as the TO field.

You can send it in batches of ~10 or something like that, but is probable that using this method your email ends in SPAM folders.

The other way is sending an email per subscriber, in a loop, doing a setTo($user) and send().